# Does Cutting Words reduce the damage taken by every target of an AoE spell or attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, bard, area-of-effect

Cutting Words says  (PHB, p. 54, emphasis mine):

> When a creature that you can see within 60 feet of you makes an attack roll, an ability check, or **a damage roll**, you can use your reaction to expend one of your uses of Bardic Inspiration, rolling a Bardic Inspiration and **substracting the number rolled from the creature's roll**.

Now, if a bard uses Cutting Words in order to alter the damage roll of a creature throwing some AoE at the party (a wizard casting a Fireball, a dragon's breath weapon, etc.), does it "cut" the damage done to **each** target affected by the AoE effect?

That would seem pretty powerful, considering that a 5th level Lore bard with a charisma of 18 can use Cutting Words once per round, up to 4 times between each short rest, using d8s to "cut" the damage done by those effects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes, Cutting Words Reduces AoE Damage Rolls

As you quoted, *any* damage roll can be reduced. While this may seem powerful—reducing a *fireball*'s damage by 1d8—it's not very.

At 5th level, a bard can use cutting word 4 times for 1d8 each time but a *fireball* at 5th level is doing **8d6 damage**. Compared to 8d6, 1d8 reduction isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: Too be fair, if you have 6 players in the AoE, it is 1d8 times 6 of damage that is averted, nearly an equivalent of (avg) superior healing potion (8d4+8), which can be very, very expensive item. Or, three cutting words equal a Mass Cure Wounds, more or less. Though if your players stay in a fireball AoE for 3 turns, they have bigger problems ;)

Comment: While true, cutting words is a *reactive* damage mitigation, not a *proactive* damage reversal. In order to use cutting words, damage has to already have been rolled. A potion can be quaffed at any time. Also, a potion is more potent because all 8d4+8 healing is applied to one character.

Comment: Comparing it to a potion is a little bit of a bad comparison. It should be compared to other uses of a bardic inspiration die. Should I reduce this fireball by 1d8, or should I potentially cause one attack to miss? Unless that one attack is fairly large, the use against a fireball is effective use of a die.

Comment: You're right. After some calculations, I've found that CW using a d8 mitigates 4%-29% (avg. 16%) of a Fireball's damage, which is much less than, say, the 50% spell damage reduction provided by the Oath of the Ancients Paladin's _Aura of Warding_ (not to mention the _Aura of protection_ already granted as a lvl 6 class feature, stacking on it). So not that big of a deal after all.

Comment: worth noting that it affects the damage roll directly, which means that it's before vulnerability/resistance/etc.

Comment: Depending on the spell this could be very potent though. It has the potential to completely nullify a high level *magic missile* trying to break your concentration.